# Understanding ImageProcessing code

Tags: android, c++, c, image-processing, android-ndk

I am new to android ndk.I have started learning through the image processing example by
[ruckus](http://ruckus.tumblr.com/post/18055652108/writing-a-basic-image-filter-in-android-using-ndk) and [by IBM blog](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-androidndk/section5.html). I am not getting few lines below.Can any one please help me to understand the code snippet?`

```
static void brightness(AndroidBitmapInfo* info, void* pixels, float brightnessValue){
    int xx, yy, red, green, blue;
    uint32_t* line;

    for(yy = 0; yy < info->height; yy++){
            line = (uint32_t*)pixels;
            for(xx =0; xx < info->width; xx++){


              //extract the RGB values from the pixel
                red     = (int) ((line[xx] & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
                green   = (int)((line[xx] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
                blue    = (int) (line[xx] & 0x00000FF );

        //manipulate each value
        red = rgb_clamp((int)(red * brightnessValue));
        green = rgb_clamp((int)(green * brightnessValue));
        blue = rgb_clamp((int)(blue * brightnessValue));

        // set the new pixel back in
        line[xx] =
          ((red << 16) & 0x00FF0000) |
          ((green << 8) & 0x0000FF00) |
          (blue & 0x000000FF);
            }

            pixels = (char*)pixels + info->stride;
        }
}
`
    static int rgb_clamp(int value) {
  if(value > 255) {
    return 255;
  }
  if(value < 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  return value;
}
```

How the RGB value are getting extracted and wht does this rgb_clamp do.Why are we setting new Pixell back and how does  pixels = (char*)pixels + info->stride; works?
I am not a c/c++ guys and not having much knowledge of Image processing.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first lets talk about one pixel. As far as i can see, it is a composition of at least 3 channels: r,g and b, which are all stored in one `uint32_t` value and has the format 0x00RRGGBB(32bit / 4 channels = 8bit per channel and thus a value range from 0..255). So, to get the separated r, g and b-values you need to mask them out, which is done in the three lines below `//extract the RGB values`. For example the red component... With the mask 0x00FF0000 and the `&` operator, you set every bit to 0 except the bits that are set in the red channel. But when you just mask them out with `0x00RRGGBB & 0x00FF0000 = 0x00RR0000`, you would get a very big number. To get a value between 0 and 255 you also have to shift the bits to the right and that is what is done with the `>>`-operator. So for the latter example: After applying the mask, you get 0x00RR0000, and shifting this 16 bit right (`>> 16`)gives you `0x000000RR`, which is a number between 0 and 255. The same happens with the green channel, but with an 8bit right shift and since the blue value is already on the "right" bit position, there is no need to shift.

Second question: What `rgb_clamp` does is easy to explain. It ensures, that your r,g or b-value, multiplied with your brightness factor, never exceeds the value range 0..255.

After the multiplication with the brightness factor, the new values are written back into memory, which happens in the reverse order of the above described extraction, this time shifting them leftwards and removing bits, that we don't want with the mask.

After one line of your image is processed, the `info->stride` is added, since for optimization purposes, the memory probably is aligned to fill 32byte boundaries and thus a single line can be longer than only image width and thus the "rest" of bytes are added to the pointer.

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, maybe the code you've posted is wrong copied but the extraction mask for the blue value is wrong in my opinion, since it should be `0x000000FF` and not `0x00000FF`(missing one 0)

Comment: Ok, i tested it. The number is wrong, but it should do no harm, since the compiler filled it up with an 0 before the FF.

Comment: oh ok thatswhy it was not affecting the result.

Comment: @AquilaRapax +1 this is relay helpful

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost I suggest you read the C book here: http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/

Next I'll go through your questions.

1. How are the RGB values extracted

   `line` is set to point to pixels parameter:

   `line = (uint32_t*)pixels;`

   That is `pixels` is an array of 32 bit unsigned integers

   Then for the height and width of the bitmap the RGB values are extracted using a combination of bitwise ANDing (`&`) and bit shifting right (`>>`).

   Lets see how you get red:

   `red     = (int) ((line[xx] & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);`

   Here we get the current line, then AND with `0x00FF0000` as mask, this gets the bits 24-16 from the `line`. So using RGB code #123456 as an example we will be left with `0x00120000` in the `red` variable. But it's still in the 24-16 bit position so we right shift 16 bits to shift the bits down to `0x00000012`.

   We do this for the green and blue values, adjusting the AND mask and number of bits to shift right.

   More information on binary arithmetic can be found here: http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter2/expressions_and_arithmetic.html
2. What does `rgb_clamp` do

   This function simply ensures the red, green, or blue values are 0 or above or 255 and below.

   If the parameter to `rbg_clamp` is -20 the it will return 0, which will be used to set the RGB value. If the parameter is `rbg_clamp` is 270 it will return 255.

   RGB values for each colour must not exceed 225 or be below 0. In this example 255 being the brightest and 0 being the darkest value.
3. Why are we setting pixel back

   It appears we are changing the brightness of the pixel, and setting the value back ready to be displayed.
4. How does `pixels = (char*)pixels + info->stride;` work?

   Without knowing the structure of `info` variable of `AndroidBitmapInfo` type, I would guess `info->stride` refers to the width of the bitmap in bytes so `line` will become the next line on the next loop iteration.

Hope that helps